# Sorting listview alphabetically by App name instead of package name

Tags: android, listview, sorting

I am trying get this ListView working and i'm trying to sort the list alphabetically by the application name instead of the package name.

MainActivity.java

```
// load list application
mListAppInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
// create new adapter
AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), getPackageManager());
// set adapter to list view        
mListAppInfo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

AppInfoAdapter.java

```
public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List list, PackageManager pm) {
    mContext = c;
    mListAppInfo = list;
    mPackManager = pm;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your `Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this)` to use `Collections.sort()`:

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
    return apps;
}
```

Comment: how to do this when we use List<PackageInfo> apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);

Answer (score 0):

An option to [biegleux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617627/sorting-listview-alphabetically-by-app-name-instead-of-package-name/11618019#11618019) code if you are using `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)`.

```
List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
```